# WebStorm debugging not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, javascript-debugger, npm-scripts

My app is a node.js app which I can run through command line using: `npm test` inside the working directory. In WebStorm, I created a new configuration that looks like this:

```
Node interpreter: /usr/local/bin/npm
Node parameters: test
Working directory ~/dev/project
```

When I hit the run button, I get the correct output:

```
/usr/loca/bin/npm test

> app@1.0.0 test ~/dev/project

something else
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But since I have breakpoints set, it should have stopped on a breakpoint instead of getting to the Process finished part. I set my code to be pretty simple just so I can test breakpoints, so it looks like this:

```
"use strict";

let foo = false; (breakpoint)
let bar = true;

if (foo === bar) { (breakpoint)
    console.log('something');
} else {
    console.log('something else'); (breakpoint)
}
process.exit(1);
```

I also tried to make this work through command line. In my site settings, I set my Built-in server to port 12345. Can accept external connections, and allow unsigned requests.

when I run it through command line, I use:

```
npm --debug-brk=12345 test
```

I get the same result: it runs all the way to the exit point without stopping on the breakpoints.

Any ideas what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: What does your test script look like in your package.json?

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/bin/npm` is definitely not a Node interpreter, it's NPM package manager that is a Node.js application itself (i.e. it's run with Node.js interpreter). And `test` is a name of npm script, not a Node.js parameter.

If you like to debug your .js file that is run via `npm test`, you need to modify your npm script to include the debug options and then use [NPM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-npm.html) run configuration for debugging. Or, just create a [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) configuration, set a valid path to Node.js execuitable there (`/usr/bin/node` or whatever it looks like on your system), then specify your `.js` file as **JavaScript file:**. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm for more info